# Is car lift required to change '03 Hyundai Santa Fe timing belt?

Tags: hyundai, santa-fe

I took my '03 Hyundai Santa Fe (V6) to the mechanic because it just shut off while driving. All the lights were on, but the engine just stopped.

I took it to a mechanic, and even though he's not 100% sure, he says it might be the timing belt. He says he needs to lift the car and remove the engine to change this timing belt.

Is changing a timing belt such a complicated task?

I've also considered getting a second opinion. The problem is that the car would need to be towed to the other garage, and that's easily $100.

Comment: Which engine is in the Sante Fe? The reason why I ask is, the V6's should have timing chains which *shouldn't* need to be changed. If the 4-cyl, then by all means it could be the culprit. If a chain broke, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: how long (in miles) since the timing belt was looked at or replaced last time?

Comment: If your mechanic is unsure if its the timing belt, but wants to charge you to remove the engine, then you NEED to take it to another mechanic! The valve cover could be removed, and the crankshaft rotated, do the valves operate as expected? If so then probably not the timing belt, unless it just jumped a few teeth, but the belt should be able to be visibly inspected from the top to see if it is worn or loose and thus likely to jump timing. As to cost to get it to another mechanic, you could rent a tow dolly for about $50.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 : it’s the V6.

Comment: Did it make any different/unusual noises when it died?

Comment: I'm wrong about the timing belt. Hyundai used a different V6 later on which uses a chain (my '08 Azera has a chain). I don't know which year they went with the newer engine, but yours would have a belt.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the car, but it's plausible that the best way to change the belt is to drop the engine. Even if dropping the engine isn't required, changing a timing belt on a modern car is often a very labor-intensive task because you have to remove so many components to get at it, for instance some combination of the radiator, fan, alternator, water pump, injection manifold, air filter box, air intake, power steering pump, etc.

However, if the timing belt went on your car there's a good chance that your engine was seriously damaged, possibly beyond economic repair. There are many other reasons your engine may have quit on you that are far easier and cheaper to fix, I would get a second opinion before investing the money in dropping the engine.

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph. That is quite likely a catastrophic failure for a 20 year old car. I don't know the Santa Fe specifically but if that belt controls valves (from the blowout drawing I saw when googling it, looks like it) you'll have valves destroyed, pistons likely affected, the cylinders bushings have likely taken a beating... AND you'll need to replace the water pump+belt. Cost >> repaired value of the car.

Comment: @StianYttervik Just replacing the whole engine is usually cheaper than trying to repair the damage AND often still not economical on an old car. But it could be the belt is just worn and the engine management computer was able to shutdown before it became a catastrophic failure.

Comment: Thanks. The issue with the 2nd opinion is that the car doesn't start, so towing it to another garage will likely cost over $100.

Comment: It's worth the $100 @rbhat, a full engine rebuild is a whole lot more.

Comment: @rbhat an engine rebuild could easily run $3-4,000. $100 for a tow to get a 2nd opinion is a worthwhile investment.

Comment: @StianYttervik that 'broken belt destroys heads' thing is only an issue if the engine is designed so the valves sweep the same space as the piston.  It's perfectly possible and common to design an engine so the extended valves do not touch the piston at TDC.  At that point a belt break is just a belt.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica You are right in that it may not have damaged valves, that depends on how much dead space there is (or rather,the compression ratio the engine was designed for). On diesels it is a sure thing, on a 20 yo gasoline engine, I would just be guessing. But that is the worst case scenario. Considering the OPs post that the engine "just died" is perhaps indication that no major damage was done. Happened to me once, and the noise the car made as it screeched to a halt was unmistakably "majer. engine. damage."

Answer (score 6):

I found this -

NOTE: Santa Fe – Due to limited space within the engine compartment it may be necessary to remove the engine from the vehicle or the gearbox mounting and left-hand side driveshaft to enable sufficient access to the timing belt.

It came from this [page](http://replace-timing-belt.com/how-to-replace-timing-chain-on-hyundai-santa-fe-2-0d-crdi-2002/).

It looks like it may be easier to remove the engine to do the work.

Comment: Hyundai and Kia motors (Hyundai owns both) from the 2000s sometimes had this problem, where the engine block was designed to be compact at the cost of being easily serviceable. I had a Kia Sedona that had to have its engine dropped several times for what should have been simple repairs otherwise.

Comment: Which requires lifting the car because they only come out the bottom?

Comment: @Mazura I think it's a logical conclusion that if there's no room to service something like a timing belt with the engine in the vehicle that there's also not enough room to remove the engine out the top of the bay. It's likely easier to remove the engine from the bottom than to remove everything else to get at the belt.

Comment: @Mazura unlikely to be impossible, but if it was designed to be dropped for removal doing so is almost certainly going to be easier than using an engine hoist to lift it out instead.  Factory cars aren't designed with making service easy for shade tree mechanics, and pros will almost always have lifts available; so making the easiest way to remove the engine being dropping it isn't going to be seen as a problem by the design engineers.

Answer (score 2):

I would get a second opinion.  It could be a variety of things that cause the engine to stop.  Many do not require the drastic step of dropping the engine.  These would include checking battery voltage, battery connections, fuel pressure, is it getting spark, etc.  Seems a bit drastic as a first step in the diagnosis process.  Just my two cents...

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that the car doesn't start, so taking it to another garage will likely cost over $100.

Comment: Is it safe to tow the car with all its wheels on the ground? That will be free (apart from a few beers) if a friend does it with their car

Comment: @CSM This is not always legal depending on location, and unless the other mechanic was very close via uncrowded slow speed streets, may not be safe, and OP may not be comfortable attempting. What would be somewhat more plausible, would be to rent a tow dolly from Uhaul (about $50) and find a friend with a vehicle with a tow hitch, this would cut the cost to less than half that of a tow truck.

Comment: Just to clarify the first point - the opinions of some people on the internet do not really qualify as a second opinion, because we haven't seen the car.